# Clone git repo hosted on a Windows shared folder from Mac OS X

Tags: windows, git, macos, smb

I host a git remote repo on a Windows shared folder. I clone it using:

```
git clone //git-host-pc/SharedFolder/MyProject/
```

This command works from a Windows PC, but on a Mac, I get this error:

```
fatal: repository '//git-host-pc/SharedFolder/MyProject' does not exist
```

Trying `git clone smb://git-host-pc/SharedFolder/MyProject` gives me this error - `fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'smb'`.

**Note:** I've found this question has been asked before mine - [Use a git repos on a windows share from osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445490/use-a-git-repos-on-a-windows-share-from-osx), however the OP there hasn't provided his exact commands, or the error messages, and that's why his question is unanswered.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, but the shared folder is visible from the Mac, I can see it in Finder.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I kind of like to think that remote file system access is an OS thing, and that cloning repos is an application-level thing, so this would be my approach:

You should just be able to *mount* that SMB share with your OS'es functions to a local directory and clone from there, instead of hoping git has a transport for SMB.

### How to mount:

Connect to the server on your Mac. Now, on your Mac, from Finder's Go menu, choose "Connect to Server." Enter the IP address you just obtained from your PC, preceded by smb://, as shown:

[image]

UPDATE: To use your PC's name instead of IP address, replace the number with the name. So if your PC's name is "MyWindowsBox", you'd use smb://mywindowsbox (not case-sensitive).

If it finds your server, you'll get prompted to enter your network credentials - by default, your Windows username and password:

[image]

### Where to find the mounted folder:

Once I mounted the `//git-host-pc/SharedFolder` in that way, I found it in `/Volumes/SharedFolder`.

Comment: How do I mount it from the command line? I only found this - http://lifehacker.com/247148/how-to-mount-a-windows-shared-folder-on-your-mac, which is about the GUI, and I still can't manage to make it work.

Comment: since the majority of work was done by sashoalm, I made this a community wiki!

Answer (score 2):

I've written this answer for those curious to know what git means by `Unable to find remote helper for 'smb'`

Git requires a helper program whenever it sees a URI such as `ftp://` or `smb://`

> When git encounters a URL of the form `<transport>://<address>`, where
>   `<transport>` is a protocol that it cannot handle natively, it
>   automatically invokes `git remote-<transport>` with the full URL as the
>   second argument
>
> Source: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote-helpers

Basically you do not have `git remote-smb` installed.  You can use `git help -a` to see what helpers you have installed.

Until somebody writes a `git remote-smb` helper, it's probably best to just mount the drive you want as mentioned in another answer.