# Push error on git repo hosted on a Windows shared folder from Linux

Tags: git, shared-directory

I've seen [this question on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32495503/clone-git-repo-hosted-on-a-windows-shared-folder-from-mac-os-x), this other [question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/91113/how-do-i-access-a-git-repository-on-a-samba-share) and this [question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264336/clone-git-from-samba-network-share), but they seem to side step my situation.

I have a shared folder hosted on windows. I've created a git repo (with `--bare` option) there to kick off a project.

On a local folder with windows, I've managed to clone the repo with:
`git clone \\<ip address>\shared_folder_name\name_of_folder_with_git_repo`

And I'm able to push normally.

Then on linux, I've cloned it successfully with:

```
git clone ~/.gvfs/smb-share:server=<ip address>,share=shared_folder_name/name_of_folder_with_git_repo
```

Looks great, but I cannot push from linux. The erro message shown is:

```
remote: error: object directory /home/my_username/.gvfs/smb-share does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates.
remote: error: object directory server=<ip address>,share=shared_folder_name/name_of_folder_with_git_repo does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates.
remote: error: object directory /home/my_username/.gvfs/smb-share does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates.
remote: error: object directory server=<ip address>,share=shared_folder_name/name_of_folder_with_git_repo does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates.
remote: error: object directory refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
remote: fatal: bad object HEAD
error: object directory /home/my_username/.gvfs/smb-share does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates.
error: object directory server=<ip address>,share=shared_folder_name/name_of_folder_with_git_repo does not exist; check .git/objects/info/alternates.
error: object directory refs/heads/master does not point to a valid object!
fatal: bad object HEAD
To /home/my_username/.gvfs/smb-share:server=<ip address>,share=shared_folder_name/name_of_folder_with_git_repo
! [remote rejected] master -> master (missing necessary objects)
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/my_username/.gvfs/smb-share:server=<ip address>,share=shared_folder_name/name_of_folder_with_git_repo'
```

In the remote repository, .git/objects/info/ is an empty folder.

I've tried adding different remotes, but to no avail. I was hoping the lack of an smb helper would not be a concern, otherwise I would not have been able to clone.

I need to find a method to be able to push relatively normally to the repo on this shared folder, preferably without requiring repeated usage of sudo.

Comment: What is preventing you from creating the repo on a private remote box, and pushing/pulling via URL ? ssh or https

Comment: @Ron What is a private remote box?

Comment: You can setup git server, like github.com or gitlab, but on a private machine of yours... checkout gitolite or gitlab .. you would just push to the hostname/IP of that box (e.g. it is remote in reference to your other workstations where you write the code.. and instead of pushing to some crazy path, you push to the hostname:reponame)

Answer (score 4):

I would not, in general, use the gvfs-fuse functionality to host or clone a repository.  It has provided some odd, non-POSIX behavior in the past, and something about it is causing the failure here.  It may be fine for transferring a few files via MTP to an Android phone, but it is not robust enough for things like Git that have serious file system consistency requirements.

You are better off using the `cifs` file system built into Linux (as described in the AskUbuntu answer you linked) or hosting an SSH server on the Windows machine and pushing that way.

Note that it isn't FUSE file systems that are problematic, but gvfs-fuse specifically; sshfs works great for this purpose and is very robust.

Comment: I'm not familiar with file systems, but if you are suggesting mounting `sudo mount -t cifs [args]` while this could be valid, it is also a big pain for me to use sudo on the linux machine. I do it on a personal machine, but I have to use sudo again every time I restart the computer. So while I think you might be correct, this wouldn't solve my problem.

Comment: Yes, I'm suggesting that as a solution; you can mark the mount as user-mountable in `/etc/fstab` so sudo is required only once, when you set it up.